# Printing a PDF with Python from variable, instead a file

Tags: python, pdf, printing

I would like to print a PDF file with an external printer. However, since I'm about to open, create or transform multiple files in some loop, I would like to print the thing without the need of saving it as a PDF file in every iteration.

Simplified code looks like this:

```
import PyPDF2
import os


pdf_in = open('tubba.pdf', 'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_in)
pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
page.rotateClockwise(90)

# Some other operations done on the page, such as scaling, cropping etc.

pdf_writer.addPage(page)

pdf_out = open('rotated.pdf', 'wb')
pdf_writer.write(pdf_out)

pdf_print = os.startfile('rotated.pdf', 'print')

pdf_out.close()
pdf_in.close()
```

Is there any way to print "page", or "pdf_writer"?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can just use variables. 
Eg.

```
path = 'C\yourfile.pdf'
os.startfile(path) #just pass the variable here
```

Comment: I understand. But I would like to print an object that hasn't been saved as a file yet.